# How to make submenu stay at the top?

Tags: html, css

I have a vertical menu and the dropdown menu won't cooperate. It currently looks like this:
[bad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvepC.jpg)

But I want it to look like this: [good](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZvepC.jpg)

```html
<html>
<head>
 
<style>

        a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}

button, .button {
  outline: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border: none;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}

section {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fafafa;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: block;
}

/* Menu */

.app-nav {
  background-color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto 0;
  min-height: 540px;
  z-index: 40;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  width: 80px;
}
.app-nav .logo {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 60px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #fff;
  width: 70px;
  padding: 10px 5px;
    
}
.links-lvl1 {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}
.links-lvl1 > li {
  position: relative;
}
.links-lvl1 > li:last-child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
    width: 79px;
}
.links-lvl1 > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.links-lvl1 li.trigger:hover .trigger-lvl2 {
  border-right-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #F5F7F9;
  box-shadow: none;
}
.links-lvl1 li.trigger:hover .links-lvl2 {
  opacity: 1;
  left: 100%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  transform: translateX(0);
  /* margin-left: 0; */
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
  transition-delay: 0s;
}
.links-lvl1 > li > a {
  /*  */
  -webkit-transition: all .15s ease-out;
  transition: all .15s ease-out;
  display: block;
  margin: 0;
  color: #7B848A;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid;
  border-right-color: #fff;
}
.links-lvl1 > li > a:hover, .links-lvl1 > li > a.selected {
  color: #5C676E;
  border-right-color: #e6e6e6;
  background-color: #F5F7F9;
  box-shadow: none;
  transition: 0.05s ease-in;
}
.links-lvl1 > li > a span {
  display: block;
}
.links-lvl1 [data-tip] {
  /*targets tooltip trigger*/
}
.links-lvl1 [data-tip]:hover .tip {
  display: block;
}
.links-lvl1 [data-tip] .tip {
  /*div*/
  display: none;
  content: "tooltip";
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top: -60%;
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  color: #495258;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 6px;
  margin: 0;
  border-radius: 2px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.links-lvl1 [data-tip] .tip:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-top: 6px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.9);
  border-left: 6px solid transparent;
  border-right: 6px solid transparent;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: -6px;
}
.links-lvl1 .faded {
  /*a*/
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #495258;
}
.links-lvl1 .fa {
  /*a > i*/
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 60px;
}
.links-lvl1 .site-label {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 26px;
  margin: 0 13px;
  color: #b8c0c4;
}

.links-lvl1.links-with-text > li > a {
  padding: 20px 0;
}
.links-lvl1.links-with-text > li > a .fa {
  line-height: 26px;
}
.links-lvl1.links-with-text > li > a span {
  line-height: 14px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.links-lvl1.links-3d > li > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #475055;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0 #262b2e;
}
.links-lvl1.links-3d > li > a.selected:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 3px;
  display: block;
  background-color: #FFA143;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #a95500;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.links-lvl1.links-3d > li:last-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 #475055;
  border-top: 1px solid #262b2e;
  border-bottom: none;
}

.links-lvl2 {
  opacity: 0;
  min-height: 200%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -300%;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 100%;
     background: #fff;
  outline: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-top-right-radius: 3px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-20px);
  transform: translateX(-20px);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .15s ease-out 0s, opacity .15s ease-out 0s, left 0s linear .15s;
  transition: transform .15s ease-out 0s, opacity .15s ease-out 0s, left 0s linear .15s;
}
.links-lvl2 .header {
  background: #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #666;
  height: 34px;
  font-size: 14px;
    height: 40px;
}
.links-lvl2 .header:hover {
    background: #fff;
}
.links-lvl2 a, .links-lvl2 .trigger-lvl3 {
  -webkit-transition: all .1s ease-out;
  transition: all .1s ease-out;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 14px 10px 14px;
  font-size: 12px;
  min-width: 180px;
  color: #8f9aa1;
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: relative;
}
.links-lvl2 a:hover, .links-lvl2 .trigger-lvl3:hover {
  background: #F5F7F9;
}
.links-lvl2 .fa {
  /*i*/
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-right: 12px;
}
.links-lvl2 .selected {
  /* applied to <a> tag */
  padding-left: 30px;
}
.links-lvl2 .selected:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  display: block;
  border-radius: 3px;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -2px;
  left: 14px;
}

.links-lvl3-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.links-lvl3-wrapper .links-lvl3 {
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: max-height .15s ease-out;
  transition: max-height .15s ease-out;
}
.links-lvl3-wrapper a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dedede;
}
.links-lvl3-wrapper .btn-menu-minus {
  float: right;
}

.links-lvl3-wrapper.expand .links-lvl3 {
  max-height: 120px;
}

</style>
</head>

<body>

     <section>
    <nav id="app-nav" class="app-nav">
        <ul class="links-lvl1 app-nav-main-links links-with-text">
            <li>
                <span class="logo"><a href="/"><img class="logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/53/Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg/512px-Google_%22G%22_Logo.svg.png"></a></span>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-lvl1"><i class="fa ion-ios-home-outline"></i><span>Dashboard</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-lvl1"><i class="fa ion-ios-bolt-outline"></i><span>Events</span></a></li>
            <li class="trigger"><a href="#" class="trigger-lvl2 link-lvl1">
                <i class="fa ion-ios-eye-outline"></i>
                <span>Design</span>
                </a>
                <div class="links-lvl2 with-header">
                    <a class="header">Dashboard</a>
                    <a href="#">link two</a>
                    <a href="#">link three</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="trigger"><a href="#" class="trigger-lvl2 link-lvl1">
                <i class="fa ion-ios-toggle-outline"></i>
                <span>Plugins</span>
                </a>
                <div class="links-lvl2 with-header">
                    <a class="header">Dashboard</a>
                    <a href="#">link two</a>
                    <a href="#">link three</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-lvl1"><i class="fa ion-ios-gear-outline"></i><span>Settings</span></a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="link-lvl1"><i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i><center><span>Powered by<br />AppSeed</span></center></a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <section class="head"><header class="head-hp"><h2>Welcome to AppSeed!</h2><h3>Let's teach you a few things so you don't get stuck.</h3><br /><br /><a class="btn-home tooltip" href="#">Teach me, Professor!<span class="tooltiptext">Coming soon!</span></a></header>
  
      <div class="app-content">
      <p>
        content goes here
      </p>
    </div></section>
  
</section>
</html>
```

I've been looking on Google and I've been trying every solution for over 2 hours. Any ideas?

Comment: remove this line: `.links-lvl1 > li { position: relative; }`. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h9jjLvqs/)

Comment: both your images (good & bad) are the same image

Comment: @haxxxton wow how did I miss that?! put that as the answer and i'll give you the points (:

Answer (score 0):

You are currently declaring your internal level 1 link list items to have `position:relative;`. This is causing the `position:absolute;` sub menu to start at the top of the list item rather than the top of the menu.

Remove the line `.links-lvl1 > li { position: relative; }` and you should find things position themselves at the top where you want.

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/h9jjLvqs/)**